# How to convert semicolon separated string into List<T>

Tags: c#

I have this string in DB `"Name 1:15,00;Name 2:30,00;Name 3:14,30"` (`name:value`) and I need to convert it to `List<MyList>`

```
public class MyList
    {
        public string Name;
        public decimal Value;
    }
```

How can do this with Linq please?

Comment: Have you tried anything so far? I suspect you'll want to use `Split` and `Decimal.Parse`...

Comment: Consider storing your data in properly formatted tables and records instead all in one string

Comment: @JonSkeet please read once more time I need to write this with LINQ, I have done it via foreach..

Comment: I've read your question several times, and it shows no effort - no sign of what you've already achieved with `foreach`, nor why you need to do it with LINQ. If you've already tried something, you should show how far you've got within your question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should do it:

```
var list = input.Split(';')
           .Select(nv => nv.Split(':'))
           .Select(nv2 => new MyList() { Name = nv2[0], Value = Decimal.Parse(nv2[1])});
```